# Scroll-snap with sticky position on children seems broken on firefox

Tags: html, css, sticky, scroll-snap

So I'm building a slideshow of sorts with the slides having position sticky set.
Works pretty good on chrome and safari, but sucks on firefox.
Maybe someone can help me out somehow?
Scroll-snapping works great on all browsers when the child doesn't have position:sticky; set.

```css
.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.slide {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

slide:nth-child(4n + 1) {
  background-color: red;
}

.slide:nth-child(4n + 2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.slide:nth-child(4n + 3) {
  background-color: green;
}

.slide:nth-child(4n + 4) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='slideshow-container'>
  <div class="slide">
    1. Slide
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    2. Slide
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    3. Slide
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    4. Slide
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    5. Slide
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    6. Slide
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    7. Slide
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    8. Slide
  </div>
</div>
```

The snippet is pretty much the same functionality as my slideshow, it works on the way down, but not on the way up.
Tho on the other mentioned browsers it works like a charm.

Comment: The first slide tends to break for some reason, maybe if I can disable position sticky only for firefox browsers..?

Comment: Not really..I saw that post, tried to implement, it works great without the position sticky..but design want's the paper-sliding effect.

Comment: Soric i am using without position sticky and its working like same. sorry for confusion but what paper-sliding effect?

Comment: If i am not wrong you want this effect with position sticky? https://jsfiddle.net/u2atbo46/

Comment: Yes, but the snippet in the post does a pretty good job of showing/explaining the effect.

Comment: The effect I want to achieve is that of a sheet of paper sliding above and over a sheet of paper, like in the snippet..

Comment: Got it but max i can get this one. https://jsfiddle.net/hyka76rj/

Comment: Thanks buddy, but that's not it.
Seems like it's bugged in firefox, anyway to report taht to someone?